# Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:. level=error, code= while sending values from child swf to parent swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to load a game.swf into main.swf and when the game in the game.swf completes it sends the score and stars got by playing the game -to the main.swf , but the problem is the main.swf is not receiving the values and giving the above said error. Please do help..

the code in main.swf to receive score and stars is,

```
var receiving_lc:LocalConnection;
receiving_lc = new LocalConnection();
receiving_lc.connect("gameToEngine");
receiving_lc.client = this;

public function saveScore(score:int, stars:int):void
{
      trace("score="+score.toString()+ " stars="+ stars.toString());
}
```

the code in game.swf to send score and stars is,

```
var sending_lc:LocalConnection;
sending_lc = new LocalConnection();

function send_it(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    sending_lc.send("gameToEngine", "saveScore", score, 2); 
}

my_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, send_it);
```

please help to solve this out....

GOT IT SOLVED....

with the help of fsbmain...

Just need to make the receiving_lc a global variable... hope it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to use domain independent local connection name, that is began with `_`, the `_gameToEngine` in your case and second add status event listener handle the `StatusEvent` error:

```
sending_lc.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onLCStatus);
protected function onLCStatus(event:StatusEvent):void
{
    trace("onLCStatus:", event.code);
}
```

UPD:
to prevent garbage collecting of the receiving_lc store the link to it in the private property:

```
private var receiving_lc:LocalConnection;
```

Comment: hey fsbmain, thanx for reply....                                        now the error is gone but still not able to receive the score...

Comment: add the same status listener to the _receiving_lc_ and trace the status, does it show anything? Do you change the lc name to __gameToEngine_? Sometimes local connection object become hanging on (often while debugging, mainly in Windows) and only restarting Windows can help.

Comment: ya i changed lc name as you've said...                              the trace("onLCStatus:", event.code); on sending side gives onLCStatus: null                                                         and on receieving side the function onLCStatus is not called at all.. thanx again

Comment: The reason local connection don't work can be the receiving_lc is garbage collected. To fix this store the link to the sending_lc (create protected property _sending_lc_ for example)

Comment: add the private property in the class that creates the _sending_lc_ instead of local variable. I updated the answer